# Finding antiderivatives for $\sqrt{1-x^a} $

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I noticed while studying integration that $\int \sqrt{1-x^2} \mathrm dx $ has a relatively simple antiderivative found by doing a trigonometric substitution.

On the other hand, $\int \sqrt{1-x^3} \mathrm dx $ can only be expressed with elliptic integrals (according to WA). The same thing occured when $a=4, 5, 6, 7...$ etc. I was wondering if there exists a proof that $\sqrt{1-x^a} $ cannot be integrated without hypergeometric or elliptic integrals when $a>2$.

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Using [Newton's generalised binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem):
$$\sqrt{1-x^a}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2}\choose k}(-x)^{ak}$$
The anti derivative is:
$$\int\sqrt{1-x^a}dx=C+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2}\choose k}\frac{(-x)^{ak+1}}{ak+1}$$

Comment: Surely you mean in the first equation $\sum {{1\over 2}\choose k} (-x^a)^k$?

Comment: Is there anyway to write the antiderivative without using an infinite series?

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for finding the antiderivative in another form besides a series. Let’s introduce a notation:

$$\text {Arc Length function of} f(x)=\text{ArcLength}(f(x))=\int_a^b\sqrt{(f’(x))^2+1}\,dx=\int_a^b\sqrt{f’^2+1}dx$$

Since your function is:

$$\int\sqrt{1-x^a}dx\mathop=^\text {set}\int \sqrt{f’^2+1}dx\implies f’^2+1=1-x^a\implies f(x)=c\pm\frac{2 i x^{\frac a2+1}}{a+2}$$

Therefore:
$$\boxed{\int\sqrt{1-x^a}dx=\text{ArcLength}\left(c\pm\frac{2 i x^{\frac a2+1}}{a+2}\right)}$$

It is [known](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6009/bezier-curve-arc-length) that finding the arc length of a cubic function, and higher real powers, is usually nonelementary. Note that the arc length of the imaginary function is needed to have the $\sqrt{1-x^a}$ otherwise, the arc length of the boxed result without the $i$ would have $\sqrt{1+x^a}$ and also note the constant of integration. To find the arclength from $x=a$ to $x=b$, use the Fundamental theorem of Calculus and evaluate $$\text {Arclength}(f(x))\big|_b-\text {Arclength}(f(x))\big|_a$$

See these [results](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=arc+length++%282+i+x%5E%28e%2F2+%2B+1%29%29%2F%28e+%2B+2%29).

Please correct me and give me feedback!

Also please see this [$\int \sqrt{1+x^n}dx$ as an arclength post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187181/arc-length-of-xn-found-using-hypergeometric-function-and-series-alternate-re)