# Arc length of $\cos(\ln(x)$) and $\sin(\ln(x))$ in closed form.

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, complex-integration, arc-length, beta-function

In this post of mine on the

> [***arc length of $cx^n$***](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187181/arc-length-of-xn-found-using-hypergeometric-function-and-series-alternate-re)

I found a general formula for the arc length of the link name above. This formula cannot cancel the radicals and radicand as this may get rid of its power to find results for $\mathrm {x,n}\not>0$. [Incomplete Beta function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/) and [**falling factorial $\ (x)_y$**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html):

$$\mathrm{Arclength(x^n) \text{ with respect to x=}\frac{xB_{-n^2x^{2n-2}}\left(\frac1{2n-2},\frac32\right)}{2\sqrt[2n-2]{-n^2x^{2n-2}}(n-1)}}$$

$$\mathrm{\text{ arc length of } x^i \text{ wrt x from 1 to 2}= -\frac{1+i}4 B_{2^{2i-2}}\left(-\frac{1+i}4,\frac32\right)-\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\left(-\frac{1+i}{4}\right)_{-\frac12}=  -\frac{1+i}4 B_{\frac14\left(cos(2ln(2))+isin(2ln(2))\right)}\left(-\frac{1+i}4,\frac32\right)-\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\frac{Γ\left(\frac{3-i}4\right)}{Γ\left(\frac{5-i}4\right)}=.780647…+.168809…i}$$

[source 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28-1%2F4+-+i%2F4%29+%28x%5E%28-2+%2B+2+i%29%29%5E%281%2F4+%2B+i%2F4%29+x+beta%28x%5E%28-2+%2B+2+i%29%2C+-1%2F4+-+i%2F4%2C+3%2F2%29-%28-1%2F4+-+i%2F4%29+%28%28x-1%29%5E%28-2+%2B+2+i%29%29%5E%281%2F4+%2B+i%2F4%29+%28x-1%29+beta%28%28x-1%29%5E%28-2+%2B+2+i%29%2C+-1%2F4+-+i%2F4%2C+3%2F2%29%29%2C+x%3D2) [source 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaLSA.jpg)

Taking the real and imaginary parts gives [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rk9xzxblpt):

$$\mathrm{x^i=e^{iln(x)}=cos(ln(x))+i\ sin(ln(x))\mathop \implies Arclength(cos(ln(x)))=Re\left(-\left(x^{2i-2} \right) _{\frac{1+i}{4}} \frac{1+i}{4}B_{x^{2i-2}}\left(-\frac{1+i}4,\frac32\right)\right), Arclength(sin(ln(x)))=Im\left(-\left(x^{2i-2} \right) _{\frac{1+i}{4}} \frac{1+i}{4}B_{x^{2i-2}}\left(-\frac{1+i}4,\frac32\right)\right)}$$

I want to simplify the arc length from 1 to 2 as I do not think the arc length from 0 to 1 converges:

$$\mathrm{Arclength(cos(ln(x)))\text{ from 1 to 2 }=Arclength(sin(ln(x)))\text{ from 1 to 2} = \int_1^2 \sqrt{
\frac{sin^2(ln(x))}{x^2}+1}dx= Re\left(-\frac{1+i}4 B_{2^{2i-2}}\left(-\frac{1+i}4,\frac32\right)\right)-\frac{\sqrt\pi}2 Re\left(\frac{Γ\left(\frac{3-i}4\right)}{Γ\left(\frac{5-i}4\right)}\right)}$$

$$\mathrm{ Arclength(sin(ln(x)))\text{ from 1 to 2} =\int_1^2\sqrt{\frac{cos^2(ln(x))}{x^2}+1}dx=Im\left(-\frac{1+i}4 B_{2^{2i-2}}\left(-\frac{1+i}4,\frac32\right)\right)-\frac{\sqrt\pi}2 Im\left({\frac{Γ\left(\frac{3-i}4\right)}{Γ\left(\frac{5-i}4\right)}}\right)}$$

Here is how to find the

> [Real and imaginary part of the Gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455306/real-and-imaginary-part-of-gamma-function)

Based on the logic of finding the real and imaginary parts of an arclength, one can get 2 new arc length results and area under arc length curves. The problem boils down to  finding real and imaginary parts of a falling factorial and incomplete beta function. Note that there is no known closed form for the real and imaginary parts of Γ(i), but if you can find a closed form or series solution to the real and imaginary parts, this will also work. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: If $f(x)\in\Bbb R$, then the arc length of $i f(x)$ is the same as $i$ times the arc length of $f(x)$;right?