# Identify the form of the nonlinear second order differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, substitution, initial-value-problems

> Identify the form of the nonlinear second order differential equation: $y''y'-x^2=0$, on the domain $ \text D[0,\infty)$ and thus find soln. given $y(0)=y'(0)=0$

Just a question about how one would solve $y(x)$ given the equation above. I used subsitution in that some $v(x) = y'(x)$ and solved that way but I do not know how to apply the intial conditions to what I get for $y(x)$ which is in an unsolvable interal form.

So I believe that there is another way of approach, I tried the taylor series method but I believe I am lost in that.

Just a quick explaination is all, I am not too confident on the taylor series expansion if that is the correct way.

Thanks

Comment: Integrate both sides to get:$$\frac12 y’^2(x)-\frac13 x^3+c_1=0$$ 

Now solve for $y’$ and integrate by doing $$y=\pm \int  \sqrt{c_1-x^3}dx$$ which is a [Gauss Hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/).

Comment: Oh let me try that!

Comment: How would one apply the initial conditions then?

Comment: I suppose you would find $y(x)$ and $y’(x)$ and just “plug in” $x=0$ to solve for $c_1$ as the special case.

Comment: Would you happen to know any other way of approaching this problem?

Comment: You could try setting $$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$ and solve using the $$\frac12y’^2-\frac13 x^3+c_1=0$$. You can also use the [Gauss Hypergeometric function series for an immediate solution](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/02/01/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how $$\frac d{dx}\frac{y’^2}2=\frac12 2y’\frac d{dx} y’=y’y’’$$

using the chain rule. Then, integrate both sides to get:$$\frac12 y’^2(x)-\frac13 x^3+c_1=0$$

Now solve for $y’$ and integrate by doing $$y=\pm \int  \sqrt{\frac13x^3+c_1}dx=\pm\frac1{\sqrt 3}\int \sqrt{c_1+x^3}dx$$

which is a [Gauss Hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/).

Here is proof of the hypergeometric function result:

> [Arc length of $x^n$ found using Hypergeometric function and series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187181/arc-length-of-xn-found-using-hypergeometric-function-and-series-alternate-re)

Which can be simplified via [Incomplete Beta function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/). I will leave the rest up to you. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Yup! thanks mate! apparently i need some reputation to upvote so there is that :D. 
The question is quite simple actually - guess I was just sleep deprived. me dum dum :p