# Fundamental Theorem Formula?

Tags: calculus

If $f'(x) = \sqrt{1 + x^3}$ and $f(1) = 0.5$, find $f(4)$

I know its the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with the equation: $$F(b)-F(a)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx$$ However, I'm not entirely sure how to solve it.

Any help?

Comment: Have you learned how to compute antiderivatives of functions like $\sqrt{P(x)}$, where $P$ is polynomial?

Comment: @Trebor No, I don't think so.

Comment: The antiderivative seems to be non-elementary.

Comment: The antiderivative of $\sqrt{1+x^3}$ is not elementary but can be expressed using hypergeometric functions (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sqrt%281%2Bx%5E3%29). Is it the original question?

Comment: Are you allowed to use numerical methods?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the interval $[1,4]$, so we have

\begin{align*}
f(4) - f(1) &= \int_1^4 \sqrt{1+x^3} dx\\
&= x \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3};\frac{4}{3};-x^3\right)\Big|_{x=1}^{x=4}\\
&= 4 \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3};\frac{4}{3};-64\right)-\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3};\frac{4}{3};-1\right)\\
&= 12.8714.
\end{align*}

So we have

$$f(4) -f(1)= 12.8714 \Rightarrow f(4) -0.5 =12.8714 \Rightarrow f(4) = 13.3714.$$

I did the integration on the right by Mathematica, see this link for the method of integration;
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152180/a-definite-integral-of-hypergeometric-function-2f1.

Comment: (+1) Your hypergeometric function is an incomplete beta function as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187181/arc-length-of-xn-found-using-hypergeometric-function-and-series-alternate-re)/[*here*](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/01/0006/).